# Azure SignalR serverless with ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions, signalr

I need to connect ASP.Net Core with SignalR in serverless mode. I couldn't find any good example of how to do it (only for Default mode) and if it's even possible?

We do have Azure functions, that work fine with serverless SignalR. But now we need to connect to another web server, that is running ASP.Net Core. How can we do it? So that Azure function and ASP.Net Core server share the same SignalR Service?

Comment: Under server-less scenario, what is the role of your ASP.NET core web server? Do you expect the app server to send messages or do you expect the SignalR clients routed to your app server?

Comment: `We do have Azure functions, that work fine with serverless SignalR. But now we need to connect to another web server, that is running ASP.Net Core. How can we do it?` Please check [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/concept-service-mode) to know more about the difference of Service mode in Azure SignalR Service. Besides, if you implement SignalR hub server in your ASP.NET Core app and you want to scale your SignalR hub with Azure SignalR Service, default mode should be the right choice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Azure SignalR Service Management SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/blob/dev/docs/management-sdk-guide.md) to interact with a serverless Azure SignalR Service from a non-Functions app. Their [samples](https://github.com/aspnet/AzureSignalR-samples/tree/main/samples/Management) have some examples of how to create a negotiate service and how to send messages. They use an IHostedService to manage the hub contexts, but I bet that could be simplified.

Here's how one would send some messages to clients:

```csharp
var serviceManager = new ServiceManagerBuilder().WithOptions(option =>
{
    option.ConnectionString = _connectionString;
    option.ServiceTransportType = _serviceTransportType;
})
.BuildServiceManager();
    
var hubContext = await serviceManager.CreateHubContextAsync("<Your Hub Name>");
    
hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("<Your SignalR Client Callback>", "<Arg1>", "<Arg2>", ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of connecting to SignalR (Replace 'localhost' with your Azure SignalR address)

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await Task.Delay(3000);

        var sender1 = SenderClient1("john");

        var sender2 = SenderClient1("papa");

        var sender3 = SenderClient1("marry");

        await Task.WhenAll(sender1, sender2, sender3);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static async Task SenderClient1(string nomeUsuario)
    {
        var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl("http://localhost:5005/sockethub", options =>
            {
                options.Headers["Application"] = "API Sender";
            })
            .WithAutomaticReconnect()
            .Build();

        await connection.StartAsync();
        await connection.SendAsync("UpdateClient", nomeUsuario);

        Console.WriteLine("Connection started.");

        connection.Closed += async (error) =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(new Random().Next(0, 5) * 1000);
            await connection.StartAsync();
        };

        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(400);

            await connection.SendAsync($"SendNotification", $"{nomeUsuario} - {DateTime.Now:G}");

            Console.WriteLine($"Send Message: {nomeUsuario} - {DateTime.Now:G}");
        }
    }
}
```

More details and an example of the complete solution can be found here: https://github.com/hgmauri/signalr-socket-dotnet5